# Get the subdomain from a string using php

Tags: php, regex, url

To get the domain name i am using this code:

```
<?php
  $myURL   = 'http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130406061745AAmovgl';
  $pattern = '/\w+\..{2,3}(?:\..{2,3})?(?:$|(?=\/))/i';
  if (preg_match($pattern, $myURL, $domain) === 1) {
    $domain = $domain[0];
  }
  $ndomain = "http://$domain";
  echo $ndomain;
?>
```

but it will output: `http://yahoo.com`
But, how i can output `http://answers.yahoo.com` this sub-domain exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should instead use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function, since it exists to do this very thing.

```php
echo parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `parse_url()`like this:

```
$urlData = parse_url($myURL);
$host = $urlData['host']; //domain + subdomain
```